# Calling modalTransitionStyle from UITableViewController - nothing happens

Tags: ios, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I finally managed to trim my code and put all the TableViewController-Methods in a separate class (away from my ViewController). I had many problems which I already solved but there is one that puzzles me.

When a selection in the table occurs, I previously loaded a modalViewController, which worked fine. But now, as I put all the Table-methods in a separate class, the modal view simply does not load. It calls the function, and steps through it nicely when I select a row in the table, but there is no view loaded on the screen of my iPhone?!

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
TaskViewController *taskViewController = [[TaskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TaskViewController" 
                                                                              bundle:nil 
                                                                                task:[listOfEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
taskViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

[self presentModalViewController:taskViewController animated:YES];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

}

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems loading the NIB file? Not returning self from TaskViewController's init method? Are you sure taskViewController is not nil? Maybe you should call this on a parent navigationController? Are you setting UIModalPresentationFullScreen as the modal presentation style?

Comment: taskViewController is not nil and returns itself. I used exactly the same code before putting all the stuff in a separate class, so it worked before fine. UIModalPresentationFullScreen does not help.